# npm ERR! missing script: start when trying to run my React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

The error is -

```
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mattj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-09T07_53_19_254Z-debug.log
```

yet I've checked my package.json and the "start" script is right there.

```
{
  "name": "gmcb-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm new to React, so is there a command I'm supposed to run before npm start? I've tried running npm init first to no avail.

Comment: in your terminal check your current `pwd` and see if you're in the same folder as you package.json

Comment: man, how embarrasing. I accidentally duplicated the containing folder when I initially created the app, it was the first thing I checked but I forgot about that. I was in the empty folder.

Comment: Happens to the best of us

Answer (score 0):

## Make sure you're in the right folder before you run a script

You can check what file you're in via the terminal command `cwd`
If you're no in the right folder make sure you're in the same folder as your package.json